# Java Deleting dynamically generated session key

Tags: java, jsp, session-state, session-variables

We have a dynamically generated session keys on load of  JSP file, suppose if we open the same page with different params in different tabs of a browser, how can we ensure that we delete the session key associated with a particular tab if we navigate to some other jsp in the application.

Comment: Why? Why do you care what the session key is? You should certainly be using HTTPS for this task, which doesn't give you any control over the session key anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A session is associated with a given browser instance. Every tab in the browser will share the same session. And that's a good thing: you don't want to re-authenticate and lose everything in the session each time you open a link in a new tab, do you?

Comment: point taken but if we have a module where in we need to edit multiple POs considering the amount of data we play around with we may not have any other option then to store those maps in session, and now if we have such multiple instances of browser tabs then my requirement was to just clear off the particular instance of session variable, one solution that i could think of was URL rewriting where in we may pass the particular session key id and then flush it, but it would be a bigger change, btw just a note i am using spring mvc framewrk.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you want to make sure every tab uses the same session key, to make sure you don't have N big data structures in session. If so, just use a unique session key, and every tab will overwrite the data of the other ones.

Comment: i am afraid that isnt the case, probably i wasnt very clear, thing is that on each tab i am processing a different entity, and some detail related to that entity is stored in session for the time user is doing some operations on that page, as soon as he navigates to other page we would clear that object from session, problem is that when navigating to a different page of application on a tab when i would intend to clear the session key associated with this tab how can i make sure that i flush the session key associated with this particular tab.

Comment: Ah, OK. I understand now. The session will time out after some time, and if it uses much memory, most app servers let you persist it to the disk or to a database. I wouldn't worry about it unless you really have memory problems. If you want to remove some values from the session before the session times out, consider storing a cache in the session, which deletes its cached values in a LRU way. See Guava's CacheBuilder, for example: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html